# How can we Send Different messages to rabbitmq per thread using jmeter AMQP publisher plugin?

Tags: jmeter, rabbitmq, jmeter-4.0

I am using jmeter to pump messages into RabbitmQ Queue.

I am sending 100 messages per second But I am able to send only same message 100 times.

I need to send different message per thread. Is it possible using Jmeter AMQP Publisher plugin?

For example I am using below JSON message:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "i_StationId": "1"
    }, {
        "dt_TimeStamp": "2019-06-10 23:59:02.000"
    }, {
        "s_Period": "1560191342"
    }, {
        "i_SubStationId": "1"
    }, {
        "datatype": "cpcb_ind"
    }, {
        "codclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "bodclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "flowclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "tssmeasured": "5.96"
    }, {
        "phmeasured": "5.96"
    }, {
        "i_CustomerId": "1"
    }],
    "date_time": "2019-06-10 23:59:02.000",
    "station_id": 1
}
```

Now in the next message i want to send another JSON message instead of same message like below.

```
{
    "data": [{
        "i_StationId": "2"
    }, {
        "dt_TimeStamp": "2019-06-10 23:59:02.000"
    }, {
        "s_Period": "1560191342"
    }, {
        "i_SubStationId": "2"
    }, {
        "datatype": "cpcb_ind"
    }, {
        "codclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "bodclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "flowclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "phclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "tssclean": "5.96"
    }, {
        "i_CustomerId": "1"
    }],
    "date_time": "2019-06-10 23:59:02.000",
    "station_id": 2
}
```

So i want to send 100 different messages at a time using AMQP Publisher. Please tell me how it is possible?

[image: Please find the attached image of how i am trying]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the jmeter functions are supported with this sampler. There are various function like thread, threadgroup, random etc. If these are supported then you need to use the function to generate different data everytime like:-

```
i_SubStationId": "${__Random(0,10)}"
```

Ref:-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

2. Check if [CSV Data set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is supported. Then, you can pass the data from csv. But, I am not sure if this is supported or not.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sunny for the suggestions.I will check out the functions and for the csv config ,If i run 10 threads can i send each csv per thread. Because i my usecase for every message my columns names would differ.

Comment: If you have 2 set of data in 1 request then csv will not work as it will pick one row of data but  functions like Random can work. Please check using functions.

Comment: yeah its solved for my usecase just i had to run multiple thread groups.where in each thread group carries different message. and your functions idea is also nice @sunny_teo . thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Please check this :-https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  . It help others.

Answer (score 0):

you can also define your own function with PreProcessor as explained here:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors

[image]

Then use this variable in the message you want to send:

[image]